# Does oxygen propagate towards stronger magnetic fields on Earth?

Tags: geomagnetism, oxygen, electromagnetism, magnetosphere, ore

I noticed Earth has variations in gravity similar to focal points for magnetic fields, both macro and micro in size, caused by magnetic material deposits. With oxygen being attracted to magnets, I wonder if the concentration of oxygen on Earth is greater where the magnetic field is stronger?

Comment: the attraction gaseous oxygen experiences is far far weaker than the velocity and  energy it has simply from temperatures.

Comment: "With oxygen being attracted to magnets," what?? Also the troposphere is well-mixed, there is no species separation there due to magnetic effects.